# C++: multiple operator definitions in different namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-overloading, shadowing

I'm troubled by conflict between two definitions of `operator<<`.

Suppose that I've been a great fan of ACE library and been using [ACE_Time_Value](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/6.3.1/html/libace-doc/a00699.html) in my code.  One day I noticed ACE 6.x was out and tried to migrate my code from ACE 5.x to 6.x.  Then I got a problem: ACE 6.x newly introduced `operator<<(std::ostream &, const ACE_Time_Value &)` in the global namespace, but my code had implemented my own version of `operator<<` since 5.x era, and two `operator<<` conflicted.  Unfortunately the output from the "official" `operator<<` is unsatisfactory and I need to keep using my own version.  How can I pretend there's no "official" `operator<<` in the global namespace?  Luckily(?) all my code is under my own namespace.

Conceptually my problem can be summarized as:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct ACE_Time_Value { };
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const ACE_Time_Value &) { os << "Apple" ; }
void foo(const ACE_Time_Value &) { cout << "Cherry" << endl; }

namespace mine {
    ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const ACE_Time_Value &) { os << "Banana" ; }
    void foo(const ACE_Time_Value &) { cout << "Durian" << endl; }

    void bar() {
        ACE_Time_Value t;
        ::mine::foo(t); // OK
        // cout << "The current time is " <<
        //   t << endl; // error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<'
    }
}

int main() {
    mine::bar();
}
```

- http://ideone.com/NJXIz9

Comment: That's a horrible problem and I can't find any good solution. Some ugly workarounds could be wrapping `ostream`s into a *helper class* `My_ostream` and provided with an `operator<<` that works just the same as the `std::ostream` version for all types but `ACE_Time_Value`, and then use those *wrapped streams* instead of standard ones.

Comment: commenting out the bad `operator<<` from the vendor headers might be the best solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up in defining a wrapper object with `operator<<`.

```
namespace mine {
    void foo(const ACE_Time_Value &) { cout << "Durian" << endl; }
    struct AceTimePrinter {
        const ACE_Time_Value &tv;
        AceTimePrinter(const ACE_Time_Value &tv) : tv(tv) { }
        inline friend std::ostream &operator<<(
                std::ostream &os, const AceTimePrinter &o) {
            const ACE_Time_Value &tv = o.tv;
            return os << "Durian" ;
        }
    };

    void bar() {
        ACE_Time_Value t;
        ::mine::foo(t); // OK
        cout << "The current time is " <<
            AceTimePrinter(t) << endl;
    }
}
```

We chose not to use inheritance because we cannot change existing method signatures in the ACE reactor framework, such as [`virtual int handle_timeout (const ACE_Time_Value &current_time, const void *act=0)`](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/6.3.1/html/libace-doc/a00208.html#a127251f675c0b6ce394f0e1c9cfd28b6)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below and make use of inheritance:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct ACE_Time_Value { };
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const ACE_Time_Value &) { os << "Apple" ; return os; }
void foo(const ACE_Time_Value &) { cout << "Cherry" << endl; }

namespace mine {
        struct New_ACE_Time_Value: ACE_Time_Value {};

        ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const New_ACE_Time_Value &) { os << "Banana" ;
            return os;
        }
        void foo(const ACE_Time_Value &) { cout << "Durian" << endl; }

        void bar() {
                New_ACE_Time_Value t;
                ::mine::foo(t); // OK
                cout << "The current time is " <<
                   t << endl; // error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<'
        }
}
```

Probably you should also make 'NewACE_Time_Value' non copyable to shrug off object slicing issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would solve your conceptual example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct ACE_Time_Value { };

namespace ACE
{
    ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const ACE_Time_Value &) { os << "Apple" ; return os; }
}

void foo(const ACE_Time_Value &) { cout << "Cherry" << endl; }

namespace mine {
    ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const ACE_Time_Value &) { os << "Banana" ; return os; }
    void foo(const ACE_Time_Value &) { cout << "Durian" << endl; }

    void bar() {
        ACE_Time_Value t;
        ::mine::foo(t); // OK
        cout << "The current time is " << t << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    mine::bar();
}
```

Since ACE is open-source, it shouldn't be too hard to apply the same modifications so that their `<<operator` overload is wrapped inside a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add "return os;" in our operator overloading (<<).
Second, add Preprocessor directives to one of two << overloading like this:

```
#ifdef Oper
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const ACE_Time_Value &) 
{
  os << "Banana"    ; return os; 
}
#endif
```